# sc.variable in web.config file

Tags: webforms

I am currently using this https://elearning.sitecore.net/Public/ContentDetails.aspx?id=7B781B1C3510447BBA22D7B0BF3251A2

In which in the setup step, it is said that on have to add a sc.variable in the web.config file.

But where should i place it?
If I add it somewhere random in the web.config file => I end up having problems with setting the authentication in IIS, and if i don't add it, it will not install it.

I am currently installing the sitescore from a zip version.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In earlier versions of Sitecore, the `<sitecore>` section was located inside the *Web.config*. At some point it was moved to a separate file called *Sitecore.config*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be added inside **sitecore** node. 
e.g.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore> 
    <sc.variable name="webDAVPrefix" value="/sitecore_files"/>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Look at sitecore.config for some uses.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend adding it to a patch file (which will add it to the main compiled sitecore node).  You can place the patch in your `App_Config/Include` folder in the Website root.  (Ex: `App_Config/Include/Settings.config`)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
     <sc.variable name="sourceFolder" value="C:\Sitecore\source" />
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```